# How do I edit a package?

Tags: packages, templates, package-writing

I downloaded a package from an article template. The thing is that I want to edit it, but don´t know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe open it in a text editor, make any changes you want, and then save it;)?  Or, what about making the question a bit more precise?  (Please, don't take any offense - just be more specific.)

Comment: It's not clear here if you mean a template to produce a document, a LaTeX package, a class or indeed something else. Could you perhaps give a little more detail, and say for example where we might find the template.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what you want to change …

### Example

Let’s assume a simple and small package `package.sty` with the following content. I use this imaginary package since it can contain all things I want to share and doens’t have that complex code. If you want to test it save the package code as `package.sty` in your document folder, i.e. the same where the text file is saved, or your user `texmf` tree*.

```
\ProvidesPackage{package}

\DeclareOption*{No options.}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{counter}

\newlength{\length}
\setlength{\length}{1em}

\newcommand{\numfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\newcommand{\pkg@printnumber}[1]{
   {\numfont(#1)}%
}

\newcommand*{\numberbox}[1]{%
   \par
   \refstepcounter{counter}%
   \fbox{%
      \pkg@printnumber{\thecounter}\hspace{\length}#1%
   }%
   \par
}
```

Which is used in a document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{package}

\begin{document}
\section{Sec 1}
\numberbox{Foo}
\numberbox{Bar}
\section{Sec 2}
\numberbox{Baz}
\end{document}
```

### Smaller changes

Can be made in your document inside the preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}` but after loading the package.

**(1) change the definition of some macros**
If you want to change the behavior of a macro you can use `\renewcommand` and set up the new definition or the tools like `\patchcmd` from [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

For example if you want to change the font of the numbers use

```
\renewcommand{\numfont}{\bfseries}                                                   % (1.1)
```

if you want to add something to the definition use `\appto` from `etoolbox`

```
\appto\numfont{\sffamily}                                                            % (1.2)
```

and if you want to replace the part of a command, e.g. replace `\numfont` with `\myfont` use `\patchcmd`. Note that you’ll need `\makeatletter`** if the macro names containing an `@`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfont}{\sffamily\itshape}
\patchcmd{\pkg@printnumber}{\numfont}{\myfont}{}{}                                   % (1.3)
\makeatother
```

**(2) change a length**
Use `\setlegth` to change a length.

```
\setlength{\length}{2em}                                                             % (2.1)
```

or again `\patchcmd` to replace it

```
\newlength{\mylength}\setlength{\mylength}{3em}
\patchcmd{\numberbox}{\length}{\mylength}{}{}                                        % (2.2)
```

**(3) change the appearance of counters**
To change the appearance of a counter, e.g. from 1, 2, 3 to I, II, III, change the definition of `\the<counter>` with `\renewcommand`, again.

```
\renewcommand{\thecounter}{\Roman{counter}}                                          % (3.1)
```

[`chngcntr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) has some more tools for this. You can add the `section` counter, for instance.

```
\counterwithin{counter}{section}                                                     % (3.2)
```

### Full MWE for the above changes

Note that not all changes are visible at once, e.g. (3.2) overwrites (3.1), so you may uncomment some lines to see the effects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{package}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% required by (1.2), (1.3), (2.2)
\usepackage{chngcntr}% required by (3.2)

% (1)
\renewcommand{\numfont}{\bfseries}                                                   % (1.1)
\appto\numfont{\sffamily}                                                            % (1.2)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfont}{\sffamily\slshape}
\patchcmd{\pkg@printnumber}{\numfont}{\myfont}{}{}                                   % (1.3)
\makeatother
% (2)
\setlength{\length}{2em}                                                             % (2.1)
\newlength{\mylength}\setlength{\mylength}{3em}
\patchcmd{\numberbox}{\length}{\mylength}{}{}                                        % (2.2)
% (3)
\renewcommand{\thecounter}{\Roman{counter}}                                          % (3.1)
\counterwithin{counter}{section}                                                     % (3.2)

\begin{document}
\section{Sec 1}
\numberbox{Foo}
\numberbox{Bar}
\section{Sec 2}
\numberbox{Baz}
\end{document}
```

### More complex changes

Make a copy of the `sty` file and save it with a new name in your user `texmf` tree*. Then open it in your favorite editor and do the changes you want.

<sup>* See [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/4918), for instance.</sup>
<sup>** See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/4918).</sup>

Comment: You mean _strongly_ when you say _hardly_, right? :) And shouldn't it be `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @cgnieder: hardly/strongly: maybe …? | `\renewcommand`: sure, thanks

Comment: hardly = kaum, strongly = stark :)

Comment: @cgnieder: I asked `dict.cc` in the meantime :-) _false friends_ :-/

Comment: A very good answer.  I think it could be made even stronger by showing a few examples with actual code.  Pick a package a demonstrate for us.

Comment: you might point out that the first three changes are meant to be made in the preamble of the new document, not in the original `.sty` file.  should be obvious to a reader, but ...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thats a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks I incorporated that in my edit.